# Filter objects based on a match in another array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to use Lodash to filter an array of objects based on a match of id's, this is what I have tried:

```
var team = _.find(this.teams, { 'id': this.newSchedule.team});
_.filter(this.yards, function(yard) {
    return _.find(team.yards, { id: yard.id });
});
```

yards data:

```
[ { "id": 1, "name": "Test" },{ "id": 2, "name": "Test 2" } ]
```

team data:

```
[ { "id": 1, "name": "Team 1", "yards": [{ "id": 1, "name" }] ]
```

I want this.yards to show the yards based on the yard id from a selected team.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to understand what you mean, does the yard `id` match the team `id`?

If so it sounds like what you need to do is first find the team with the same `id` then grab that teams yards. Therefore I would use the map function twice:

```
const result = this
  .yards
  .map(y => team.find(t => t.id === y.id)) // join with the right team
  .map(t => t.yards)                       // reduce to that teams yards
```

Comment: Sorry, I want to filter this.yards to show only the yards the team has access to, so a match from the teams -> yards -> yard.id to match in the yard.id in this.yards. Hopefully that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

As `team` is an array, you need to iterate it before doing the `_.find` on an individual element in that array. It doesn't help that you called your variable `team` (singular). `teams` would make more sense.

Here is how you would change your lodash code:

```js
var yards = [ { id: 1, name: "Test" },{ id: 2, name: "Test 2" } ],
    teams = [ { id: 1, name: "Team 1", yards: [{ id: 1, name: "Missing string" }] } ]

    result = _.filter(this.yards, function(yard) {
      return _.some(this.teams, function(team) {
        return _.find(team.yards, { id: yard.id });
      });
    });

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

So this returns the yards that are related to at least one team.

Comment: Hi sorry, I should have been more clear that I had already selected a 'team' from the teams data: var team = _.find(this.teams, { 'id': this.newSchedule.team}); Have updated my question.

Comment: In that case your question is still confusing, because it still shows `team` as an array. Secondly, the code you have then seems to works fine (see https://jsfiddle.net/4yocg6wj/ although it is impossible to guess what `this` is in your case), so there is another issue. Please provide enough code for us to be able to reproduce the issue. Also provide the desired output.